# is it possible to do this in jsf?

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I have a / group of radio buttons , and a CommandButton

Two cases

1)When one of the button is clicked + The command Button is clicked,  I should display some other section(say a DIV) and the execution stops. means, The Command Button should not submit the form to the server

1)When **NONE** of the button is clicked + The command Button is clicked,I should submit the form to the server and display a Faces Message that he has not selected anything.

I don't want to do this alert as a JavaScript popup.Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _"When one of the button is clicked"_ are you referring to selecting radio buttons or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible with a little help of JavaScript. Easiest would be to give the ID of the section div elements as radio button value and then loop through all radio buttons and show/hide the element based on the button's `checked` state. At end you should let the JS function return `false` when any button is checked so that the button's default action won't be invoked and the form won't be submitted to the server.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectOneRadio id="radio">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="section1" itemLabel="Show section1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="section2" itemLabel="Show section2" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="section3" itemLabel="Show section3" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:commandButton id="button" value="show section" 
        action="#{bean.submit}" onclick="return showSection(this.form)" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="section1" class="section">section1</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="section2" class="section">section2</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="section3" class="section">section3</h:panelGroup>
```

with this CSS

```
.section {
    display: none;
}
```

and this JS

```
function showSection(form) {
    var radiobuttons = form['form:radio'];
    var selected = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
        var radiobutton = radiobuttons[i];
        var section = document.getElementById(radiobutton.value);
        if (radiobutton.checked) {
            section.style.display = 'block';
            selected = true;
        } else {
            section.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    return !selected; // Submits to server if none is selected.
}
```

and JSF bean (we of course assume that this action will *only* be invoked if none is selected).

```
public void submit() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Please select!"));
}
```